# How to use in_array if the array contain only one element?

Tags: php, arrays

I loop through a big array and got a small array of ids

```
foreach ($cats as $cat)
    $cat_ids[] = $cat->term_id;
```

sometimes the $cat_ids has only one element. `Array ( [0] => 123` )

When I check if a random id is in this $cat_ids array, `if( in_array( $int,$cats_ids ))`

I may get error message of $cat_ids "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array,..."

How can I check if $int is in $cat_ids properly?

Comment: Even with one element, `$cat_ids` is still an array.

Comment: your array name is `$cat_ids` and you are using `$cats_ids` there

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't find this mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @Nerd-Herd: Now that you know it was the problem, you should probably post it as an answer.

Comment: @Jenny - If it was a typo, how did it work when there were more elements?

Comment: @JoyceBabu It has never been mentioned that it worked with more elements.

Comment: Doesn't the title imply that? "How to use in_array if the array contain only one element"

Comment: Try var_dump($cat_ids) if you get the error

Comment: I learned a great lesson today, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the array has zero values or more. It just needs to be an array. So you have some error with the variable. If it is not an array, you could always typecast it into an array using `(array)$cats_ids`

Answer (score 4):

Your array name(in the loop) is `$cat_ids` and you are using `$cats_ids` in the function `in_array()`